# Android: Paint not Displaying atop Fragment View

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, canvas, paint

I have an instance of a paint and canvas in a fragment view and I want to be able to draw on it at will.

The problem: my circular shapes i'm trying to paint on top of my fragment view's background aren't showing up properly; the circle is getting clipped as if it's being drawn behind the fragment.

Below, the orange view is a separate from my fragment, don't expect to see the blue circle there. The white view, however, is my fragment and I expect the blue circle to be drawn on top of it complete. Instead, I see a clipped blue circle (looks like a rectangle) within the white fragment view. Even when I don't set the android:background xml attribute for this view, the blue circle still appears clipped. 
[image]

**What do I need to change in my code to get my canvas shapes to display on top of the fragment view (overlapping it)?**

**FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java**

```
public class FragmentNeckDisplayMenu extends Fragment {
    private static View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_neck_display,container,false);

        //Configure Paint Canvas
        LinearLayout paintSurface = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        paintSurface.addView(new NeckGlow(getActivity()));
    }
    //paint test
    class NeckGlow extends View {
        Paint mPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public NeckGlow(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);   
            mPainter.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPainter.setAlpha(255);
            canvas.drawCircle(25, 900, 200, mPainter);
        }
    }
}
```

**menu_fragment_neck_display.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a LinerLayout with orientation horizontal (default). That means that you Canvas is being layout right next to the Buttton. You can try using FrameLayout and the canvas *should* be drawn on top of the button.